# I would like to change the color of a row if two rows with the same contents in one column differ in value in another column

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, countif

So I have been working on this for a while now but can't seem to get it.
Essentially if the contents in column C (NAME) match, I need to see if their rows match value in column K (Y/N).

If they differ in Column K, the entirety of both rows should turn yellow.
Additionally, I would like that if they match in column C, and they are both "No" in column K, both rows turn red.

I believe this to be done as a custom rule in conditional formating but this is all I could come up with, unsure how to proceed. (I am operating in Google Sheets since its a shared doc but I can manage with Excel.

```
=AND($C1<>"",COUNTIF($C:$C,$C1)>1, COUNTIFS($C:$C,$C1,$K:$K,$K1)>0)
```

Some sample data; here both of Jane's rows should be red and Alex's rows should be yellow:

```
43425.45184 NA  Morg    4   7   5   6   7   6   6   Yes
43423.65523 NA  Alee    4   9   8   7   8   8   9   Yes
43425.4461  NA  Alee    4   8   8   8   8   8   8   Yes
43420.93822 NA  Bale    4   8   7   7   6   10  7   Yes
43424.40326 NA  Jane    5   9   8   8   9   9   7   No
43430.45766 NA  Jane    5   10  10  10  10  10  10  No
43424.51362 NA  Alex    3   8   8   8   4   6   6   Yes
43430.48237 NA  Alex    4   6   3   5   2   7   6   No
43428.76583 NA  Allison 4   8   8   8   7   6   8   Yes
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and an expected outcome?

Comment: @EliotK done@!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think these two will do it.

> =AND(COUNTIF($C:$C,$C1)=2,COUNTIFS($C:$C,$C1,$K:$K,"No")=2)

Above is fill red

> =AND(COUNTIF($C:$C,$C1)=2,COUNTIFS($C:$C,$C1,$K:$K,"Yes")=1)

Above is fill yellow

[image]

[image]

Comment: red works, but yellow does not because it applies to Yes as well. It should only go yellow if one in the same name, one is yes one is no. see sample data

Comment: So there are never more than 2 instances of the same value in column C?

Comment: I've added a screenshot. Make sure the applies to ranges are correct.

Comment: ahhh, I see I was messing up the range. Thank you!

Comment: My pleasure. I should have mentioned before.